# Omitting personal pronouns in informal conversation

Tags: conversational-deletion

When chatting informally, either in person or over text, it seems common to shorten the sentences by omitting pronouns:

> - Made it home?
>
> - Yeah. Should've taken a bus.
>
> - Hope you don't catch a cold!

However, in some cases it sounds unnatural, even if the pronoun is heavily implied:

> - *Closed the door?
>
> - *Didn't.
>
> - *Should close it.

Are there any rules as to when one can and cannot shorten their sentences in this way, or does it boil down to some phrases just being more idiomatic than others?

Comment: There are no rules.  Your second conversation would probably be *Door's locked?*  When asking whether someone wants the door closed: *(Shall I) Close the door?* or *(Shall I) Leave it open?*

Comment: Look up the terms ["pronoun drop"](https://academic.oup.com/jole/article/2/2/188/3091421) and ["diary drop"](https://awweir.files.wordpress.com/2017/04/weir-ug-diss.pdf) - you will probably find some useful information there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "conversational deletion" and you can [read all about it on our sister site](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/66994/2303), English Language & Usage, where member John Lawler says:

> In general, exposed first-person subjects are vulnerable in statements, and second-person in questions, and any exposed pronoun is vulnerable if it is recoverable from later in the sentence.

Meaning that where the subject of a sentence is clear, it is frequently omitted in conversation.

Comment: I like that bit about *...if it is recoverable from later in the sentence*. I don't agree with OP in the first place that "pronounless" ***Locked the door?*** is inherently unnatural, but I'd certainly accept that in practice, ***Lock[ed] the door, did you?*** is more likely.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But you can pretty much always do that with a tag question, can't you? Anyway, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston, Pullum, et al. (2002) classifies the phenomenon as simply ellipsis (*Further cases of ellipsis*) on pp.1540–3.

Comment: @userr2684291: ***But can pretty much always do that with a tag question, can't you?*** No - I don't think my pronounless version of your first sentence above would be idiomatically acceptable to any native speaker. Not sure exactly why though - it's certainly not that you can't delete second-person in the context of a "modal, auxiliary" verb like ***can***, because there's nothing remotely unusual about ***Can't wait, can you?***. But there's something weird involving negation there, because we wouldn't do that deletion in ***You can wait, can't you?***

Comment: @FumbleFingers The described "erosion" works its way from the beginning of the sentence up until it encounters a "non-vulnerable" element which is why the first example doesn't work. Your second example assumes you would've said just *You can wait* – and when would you say that, hehe? CGEL says this kind of ellipsis (of personal pronoun subject only) occurs mainly with *I*, *there*, *it*, but mentions that other pronouns are *possible* sometimes (*Looks a bit put out, doesn't he?*), and in some cases an antecedent is needed: *What's **the new guy** like?* ~ *(**He**) Can't play at all.*

Comment: CGEL places further restrictions on other similar kinds of ellipsis. *Anaphoric retrievability* is best seen in examples of ellipsis called **gapping**: [i] *Kim **lives** in Perth, Pat __ in Melbourne.* [ii] *Tom **will** play the guitar and Mary __ sing.* [iii] A: *I **will now show you how to make** clafouti.* B: *And I __ custard.*

Comment: @userr2684291: Bear in mind that as a native speaker I don't need to consult CEGL to know what's idiomatic and what's not. But whereas I know perfectly well that ***Can wait, can't you?*** would be an *extremely* unlikely "deletion", even though the "opposite, non-negated" version is common, I can't say anything you've just written sheds any light on *why* that should be so.

Comment: The question isn't about the phenomenon *per se*; it's about why it happens sometimes and not others, even when the "vulnerability" would appear to be the same. I would agree with OP that *Closed the door?* is not nearly as likely as *Made it home?*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo That's because you'd ask *Have you made it home?* but apparently not *Have you closed the door?*, I assume.

Comment: @userr2684291: Not really. *Have you closed the door?* is legit and common enough.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Apparently not common enough to establish omitting the *Have you*.

Comment: @userr2684291: Not really. It's damn common :)   Perhaps **Closed the door?** sounds too much like the request  "Close the door" that is *(Would you please) Close the door*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The closest I can get you to the *why* is "it's more common with certain pronouns than others". Why not omit the *you*? Because it's not usually omitted – and that's how everything in language works, and a grammar may only describe it. For some things there's a "reasoning" which works **within** that system only. When you get to the very bottom, the only reason is *because that's how you say it in English*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Maybe. With *see* and *drive* and *make* the participle is quite distinguishable (and easy to pronounce – at least I think *closed the* is a bit difficult to enunciate properly if you want *closed* to be heard, especially when you've already resorted to ellipsis/laziness/hurriedness).